# Need help with combinatorics problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I find the number of solutions to the following problem: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=21 $ where $x_i$,  $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, is a nonnegative integer such that $0\le x_1\le 3, 1\le x_2 < 4, x_3≥15$.

I know how to solve problems where $x_i$ is restricted to be greater than or equal to some constant, "$x_i\ge  a$". But here there are two "less than or equal two" restrictions. Do I have to look at 4 different cases to solve this? (This is beginner discrete mathematics level.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in a polynomial or power series constructed so as to reflect the constraints. So for example the factor corresponding to $0\le x_1\le 3$ is $1+x+x^2+x^3$.

Edited to address OP's question in comments below:
You can take anywhere from $0$ to $3$ $x_1$s and anywhere from $1$ to $3$ $x_2$s. So if we were only considering $x_1$ and $x_2$, we would want to look at $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(x+x^2+x^3)$. The coefficient of, say, $x^5$ in the expansion of that polynomial would be the number of ways to get $5$ $x$'s from $0$ to $3$ $x_1$s (from the power of $x$ in the first factor) and $1$ to $3$ $x_2$s (from the power of $x$ in the second factor --- if the two exponents add to $5$, then you would get $5$ things altogether. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Our book doesn't explain this very well. Where do you get x^21 and 1+x+x^2+x^3 from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordinary generating functions to solve it. The generating function corresponding to the choices for $x_1$ is $1+x+x^2+x^3$ (first term corresponding to $x_1=0$, second to $x_1=1$, so on). The one corresponding to $x_2$ is $x+x^2+x^3$, and the one corresponding to $x_3$ is $x^{15} + x^{16} + \ldots$. Multiply these together and look at the coefficient for $x^{21}$ to get a sum of 21.

Answer (score 0):

So you can compute the function $F(a_1,\ldots,a_5; n)$, which is the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + \ldots + x_5 = n$, where $x_i \ge a_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots 5$, as you say.

Now, if the tuple $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ is a solution to the original equation with restrictions, the tuple $(x_1, x_2-1, x_3-15,x_4,x_5)$ is a solution to the equation $y_1 + y_2 + y_3+ y_4 + y_5 = 5$ with restrictions $0 \le y_1 \le 3, 0 \le y_2 \le 2$. And similarly we go back from $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)$ for the latter to $(y_1, y_2+1, y_3+15,y_4,y_5)$ for the former. So these equations with restrictions have the same number of solutions.

So we can restrict to the equation $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 5$, with $0 \le y_1 \le 3, 0 \le y_2 \le 2$ (and all other $y_i$ merely positive integers). This equals $F(0,0,0,0,0; 5) - F(4,0,0,0,0;5) - F(0,3,0,0,0) + F(4,3,0,0,0; 5)$: we take all positive integer solutions and subtract all the ones with $y_1 \ge 4$, because of the first condition, and also substract all the ones with $y_2 \ge 3$, because of the second condition on the $y_i$, and add all the ones that have both the conditions (or we'd substract those twice); the latter is $0$ in this case, as $y_1 \ge 4, y_2 \ge 3$ forces the sum to be too big. I added it to show the general principle.

Now you can compute the answer.